# When to use TryAddSingleton or AddSingleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've noticed in some .NET Core examples there are calls to  `TryAddSingleton`, and in some `AddSingleton` when registering services.

Decompiler shows that TryAdd (called by TryAddSingleton) adds the specified param "descriptor" to the "collection" if the service type hasn't been already registered.

Does it mean that it's always safer to use TryAddSingleton, in case if some other method/library already registered the same class?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As you already noticed, the difference between `TryAddSingleton` and `AddSingleton` is that `AddSingleton` always appends the registration to the collection, while `TryAddSingleton` only does this when there exists no registration for the given service type.

When multiple registrations exist for the same service type, but a single instance is requested, .NET Core will always return the **last one registered**. This means that the behavior of `AddSingleton` is to effectively replace instances for non-collection resolution, for instance:

```
services.AddSingleton<IX, A>();
services.AddSingleton<IX, B>(); // ‘replaces’ A
IX x = container.GetService<IX>(); // resolves B
```

For collection resolution however, `AddSingleton` behaves as a collection ‘append’ of already existing registrations for that service type. For instance:

```
services.AddSingleton<IX, A>();
services.AddSingleton<IX, B>();
IEnumerable<IX> xs = container.GetServices<IX>(); // resolves A *and* B
```

With `TryAddSingleton` however, the registration will not be added when there already exist registrations for the given service type. This means that, independently of when a service type is resolved as one instance or as a collection of instances, the registration will not be added when there is at least one registration. For instance:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IX, A>(); // adds A
services.TryAddSingleton<IX, B>(); // does not add B, because of A
IX x = container.GetService<IX>(); // resolves A

services.TryAddSingleton <IX, A>(); // adds A
services.TryAddSingleton <IX, B>(); // does not add B, because of A
IEnumerable<IX> xs = container.GetServices<IX>(); // resolves A only
```

`TryAddSingleton` is especially useful for framework and third-party library code that wishes to register its own components to the container. It allows an application developer to override the framework or library’s default registration, even if the application developer registered that component before the framework or third-party `AddXXX` extension method is called. For instance:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IX, A>(); // adds A
services.AddThirdPartyLibrary(); // calls services.TryAddSingleton<IX, B>();
IX x = container.GetService<IX>(); // resolves A
```

If the third-party library had called `AddSingleton` instead of `TryAddSingleton`, the application developer’s `A` will always be overridden, which is likely to result in unexpected behavior. As an application developer, you typically know what you registered, which makes the use of `TryAddSingleton` less useful in such a case.

I would even argue that, from perspective of an application developer, the behavior of `AddSingleton` can be very tricky, because it implicitly overrides an existing registration, without any warning whatsoever. My experience is that this behavior can cause hard to spot configuration errors. A safer design would have been to have `AddSingleton`, `AppendSingleton` and `ReplaceSingleton` methods, where `AddSingleton` would throw an exception in case a registration exists, and `ReplaceSingleton` would actually discard the existing registration.

Comment: Thank you!
this answer inspired me to complete work on my library. https://github.com/ezzabuzaid/tiny-injector

I have added the above functionality which works pretty well!